# Does a client send a transaction request to every validator in the network in hyper ledger sawtooth?

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

I am new to the hyper ledger-sawtooth platform. I read the documentation many times but some couldn't figure out if the client requests only a single validator or whether it requests multiple validators. If a client requests a single validator, how can we be sure about the integrity of the data?

Comment: Typically a client request is directed to a single validator. But the request can be made to any validator node that also has the REST-API service running. The validators themselves reconcile the data so that each of the validators data stores are synchronized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a nutshell: 
In sawtooth, a client usually connects and sends batches to rest-api, which in turn forwards to the validator the rest-api itself is connected to. The batches are in turn added into a block by the validator and then sent (directly/indirectly) over to other validators in the entire sawtooth network. The consensus, merkle trie and other algorithms work together to ensure the integrity and synchronization of the blockchain across all participating validators.